# Calculating cooccurrence probabilities for pairs of words in a document

Tags: c++, algorithm, interview-questions, clustering, natural-language-processing

It is a 1.5 hour coding test, started the moment when the question was sent by email. My solution was done under the strict condition. I was not told anything before the test.

The [question](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1WTDPIHhk6SZW85cTNwaEk5M2x3dmlHT1RrMF9xSUpkVEk4) is about counting word occurrence in natural language processing.  Paraphrased, it asks:

> Given an input document and a range *k* (with 1 ≤ *k* ≤ 5), calculate all cooccurrence probabilities for various pairs of words *A* and *B*:
>
> $$ p(A, B, k) = \frac{\textit{cooccurrence(A, B, k)}}{\textit{count}(A)} $$
>
> In other words, out of every time the word *A* appears, what is the probability that *B* appears within ±*k* words?

My solution in C++ is below. I think I could do better in my attempt. What are the areas that I should prepare & learn? I failed to come up with a better data structure under the exam condition.

During the test, I briefly tried stack but later found out I couldn't iterate all elements without changing the data structure. That wasted my time and I wonder if a stack can be used?

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const auto file = argv[0];
    const auto K = atoi(argv[1]);

    std::string line;

    // Mapping for coocurrence
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, unsigned> coo;

    std::map<std::string, unsigned> count;

    // History of the last K words
    std::vector<std::string> hist;

    std::ifstream ss(file);

    while (std::getline(ss, line))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> toks;
        boost::split(toks, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));

        for (auto &tok : toks)
        {
            boost::replace_all(tok, ",", "");
            boost::replace_all(tok, ".", "");
            boost::replace_all(tok, "!", "");
            std::transform(tok.begin(), tok.end(), tok.begin(), ::tolower);

            if (tok == "\t" || tok == "," || tok == "")
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Required for dennominator
            count[tok]++;

            std::set<std::string> known;

            // Checking the last K history
            for (auto &i : hist)
            {
                if (!known.count(i))
                {
                    coo[std::pair<std::string, std::string>(tok, i)]++;
                    //coo[std::pair<std::string, std::string>(i, tok)]++;
                }

                known.insert(i);
            }

            if (hist.size() != K)
            {
                hist.push_back(tok);
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 * Reconstruct the history of recent words
                 */

                for (auto i = 0; i < hist.size()-1; i++)
                {
                    hist[i] = hist[i+1];
                }

                hist[hist.size()-1] = tok;
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> toks;
    boost::split(toks, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> toks;
        boost::split(toks, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));

        std::string x1 = toks[0];
        std::string y1 = toks[1];
        std::transform(x1.begin(), x1.end(), x1.begin(), ::tolower);
        std::transform(y1.begin(), y1.end(), y1.begin(), ::tolower);

        if (!count.count(x1))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        const auto den = count.at(x1);
        auto num1 = coo.count(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(x1, y1)) ? coo.at(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(x1, y1)) : 0;
        auto num2 = coo.count(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(y1, x1)) ? coo.at(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(y1, x1)) : 0;

        if (x1 == y1)
        {
            num1++;
            num2++;
        }

        std::cout << (double)(std::max(num1, num2)) / den << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The task quoted said `various pairs of words A and B`, you seem to be handling _each and every pair_. (I'd probably claim the task insufficiently specified, associate ordinals with "each" word and wait for queries…)

Comment: @greybeard I think the question is asking about each and every pair within the K distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a `std::vector<std::string>` for `hist`, a history of the last *K* words.  To limit that vector to size *K*, you shift the words over like this:

> ```
>     if (hist.size() != K)
>     {
>         hist.push_back(tok);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         /*
>          * Reconstruct the history of recent words
>          */
>
>         for (auto i = 0; i < hist.size()-1; i++)
>         {
>             hist[i] = hist[i+1];
>         }
>
>         hist[hist.size()-1] = tok;
>     }
> ```

But that loop is essentially doing [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) on the first element — and, as you can see, it's an inefficient O(*K*) operation on a vector.

A [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) would be an improvement:

> `std::deque` (double-ended queue) is an indexed sequence container that allows **fast insertion and deletion at both its beginning and its end**. … As opposed to `std::vector`, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.

That non-contiguous caveat is a bit of a disappointment, though.  Since you want a bounded-size buffer where adding an entry at the end causes the first entry to drop out, the data structure that you really want is a [circular-list](/questions/tagged/circular-list).  As luck would have it, **[Boost has a circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
```

Each file should be self-sufficient by including the specific header a symbol relies on. You forgot to remove the `<sstream>` and `<stack>` artifacts. You are missing:

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::transform
#include <cstdlib>    // std::atoi
#include <string>     // std::string<>
#include <utility>    // std::pair<>
```

Prefer to organize your headers in logical groups.  A common logical ordering would be by ascending hardiness.  Code that isn't as rigorously tested is processed before other libraries that are better tested.

When searching a list of includes, binary search is faster than linear search. so prefer to order lexicographically.

```
#include "class.h"            // Prototype/Interface

#include "range/algorithm.h"  // Project-Level libraries
#include "utils/string.h"

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>  // Third-Party Libraries
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

#include <algorithm>          // Standard Library
#include <cstdlib>
// ...
#include <vector>
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const auto file = argv[0];
    const auto K = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Always check `argc` before accessing `argv`. `argc` is only guaranteed by the standard to be non-negative, not non-zero.  `argv[0]` is also special.

> **3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]**
>
> \$^2\$ ... If `argc` is nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte strings (*NTMBS*s) (17.5.2.1.4.2) and `argv[0]` shall be the pointer to the initial character of a *NTMBS* that represents the name used to invoke the program or `""`.

---

```
    // Mapping for coocurrence
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, unsigned> coo;
```

Don't say in comments what can be stated in code.  Keep code-related comments minimal and crisp.  When something is important and not obvious (unusual/obscure code), clarify through a comment.

Don't pay for what you don't use.  Unless you require that keys be sorted at all times, prefer using `std::unordered_[map|set]`.

---

```
    std::ifstream ss(file);
```

Give variables appropriate names.  `ss` doesn't give the reader an idea of what the variable is holding.

---

```
    while (std::getline(ss, line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> toks;
        boost::split(toks, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

`std::string::operator>>` already delimits on whitespace.

---

```
        boost::replace_all(tok, ",", "");
        boost::replace_all(tok, ".", "");
        boost::replace_all(tok, "!", "");
```

This is probably not the intended purpose of `boost::replace_all` as copies and buffers are used in the background to handle resizing.  You could just use the erase-remove idiom.

```
        auto is_nonalpha = std::not1(std::fun_ptr(std::isalpha));
        tok.erase(std::remove_if(tok.begin(), tok.end(), is_nonalpha), tok.end());
```

C++17 will introduce [uniform container erasure](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4273).

```
        std::erase_if(tok, is_nonalpha);
```

---

```
            for (auto i = 0; i < hist.size()-1; i++) {
                hist[i] = hist[i+1];
            }

            hist[hist.size()-1] = tok;
```

Prefer to use standard algorithms as they may afford you optimizations.

```
            std::copy(std::next(hist.begin()), hist.end(), hist.begin());
            hist.back() = tok;
```

Rather than paying the cost of cycling, consider using a Circular container adaptor.

---

```
    if (!count.count(x1)) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Are you sure you want to exit if a word doesn't appear in the corpus?  This doesn't seem like a case where termination is necessary.

---

```
    std::cout << (double)(std::max(num1, num2)) / den << std::endl;
```

`std::endl` outputs `'\n'` and flushes the stream.  If you did not intend to flush the stream, just output `'\n'`.

---

> My solution in C++ is below. I think I could do better in my attempt. What are the areas that I should prepare & learn? I failed to come up with a better data structure under the exam condition.

Seems like you already know where you should be looking.

> During the test, I briefly tried stack but later found out I couldn't iterate all elements without changing the data structure. That wasted my time and I wonder if a stack can be used?

You can write a non-owning read-only adaptor.  The underlying container is a protected data member of the Standard Library container adaptors.